How to solve the "no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf " message when use max() function
When I process the following data containing NA the max function prompts a warning message.
For the following data df, I want to calculate the maximum value for each group.
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Var_1 = c("Grp 1", "Grp 1", "Grp 1", "Grp 2", "Grp 2", "Grp 2", "Grp 3", "Grp 3", "Grp 3"),
                 Var_2 = c(1,2,3, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, 9))

ck <- df %>%
      group_by(Var_1) %>% 
      summarise(max_var = max(Var_2, na.rm = TRUE))

print(ck)

  Var_1 max_var
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 Grp 1       3
2 Grp 2    -Inf
3 Grp 3       9

If I don't add condition na.rm = TRUE to the max function, the result is NA for Grp 3. If I add the condition na.rm = TRUE, the records for Group 2 are deleted, and then the warning message "no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf" is thrown.
The result I was hoping for was



Var_1
max_var




Grp 1
3


Grp 2
NA


Grp 3
9



Does anyone have any suggestions on how to handle this WARNING message and results? Thanks.
I've tried deleting all the NA results first and then calculating with summarize(max()), but this causes Grp 2 to disappear. I want to keep this group and let the result is NA.
df <- data.frame(Var_1 = c("Grp 1", "Grp 1", "Grp 1", "Grp 2", "Grp 2", "Grp 2", "Grp 3", "Grp 3", "Grp 3"),
                 Var_2 = c(1,2,3, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, 9))


ck <- df %>%
      filter(!is.na(Var_2)) %>%
      group_by(Var_1) %>% 
      summarise(max_var = max(Var_2, na.rm = TRUE))

print(ck)

  Var_1 max_var
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 Grp 1       3
2 Grp 3       9


Another option could be first slicing the maximum value per group using slice_max and after that remove the duplicated rows for the group with only NA's like this:
library(dplyr)

ck <- df %>%
  group_by(Var_1) %>% 
  slice_max(Var_2) %>%
  distinct()

print(ck)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Groups:   Var_1 [3]
#>   Var_1 Var_2
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 Grp 1     3
#> 2 Grp 2    NA
#> 3 Grp 3     9

Created on 2024-04-23 with reprex v2.1.0

Use slice_max(with_ties = FALSE) and you can avoid the call to distinct()

You can create your own function to return NA conditional on all of the values being NA:
fn <- function(x, na.rm=FALSE) {
   if(all(is.na(x))) NA else max(x, na.rm = na.rm)
}

df %>%
  summarise(max_var = fn(Var_2, na.rm = TRUE), .by=Var_1)

  Var_1 max_var
1 Grp 1       3
2 Grp 2      NA
3 Grp 3       9


Convert to factor, remove NA rows, summarise then use tidyr::complete to get missing factor levels:
df %>%
  mutate(Var_1 = as.factor(Var_1)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Var_2)) %>%
  group_by(Var_1) %>% 
  summarise(max_var = max(Var_2, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  complete(Var_1)

# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   Var_1 max_var
#   <fct>   <dbl>
# 1 Grp 1       3
# 2 Grp 2      NA
# 3 Grp 3       9


You can replace Inf by NA and suppress the warning like this:
df %>% 
  summarise(max_var = {
    res <- suppressWarnings(max(Var_2, na.rm = TRUE))
    if_else(is.infinite(res), NA_real_, res)
}, .by = Var_1)

#   Var_1 max_var
# 1 Grp 1       3
# 2 Grp 2      NA
# 3 Grp 3       9


For the fun of it, here is a solution relying on the fact that pmax does not produce Inf values.
From ?pmax:

However, ‘pmax’ and ‘pmin’
return ‘NA’ if all the parallel elements are ‘NA’ even for ‘na.rm
= TRUE’.

Idea is that you first transform your data into wide format and then pamx over all columns:
library(tidyr)
(df_wide <- df %>% 
  mutate(ord = paste0("M", 1:n()), .by = Var_1) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = Var_2, names_from = ord))

# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#   Var_1    M1    M2    M3
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Grp 1     1     2     3
# 2 Grp 2    NA    NA    NA
# 3 Grp 3     7    NA     9

df_wide %>%
  mutate(
    max_var = do.call(
      pmax, 
      c(select(., matches("^M\\d+$")), 
        na.rm = TRUE)
    )
  ) %>% 
  select(-matches("^M\\d+$"))

# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   Var_1 max_var
#   <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 Grp 1       3
# 2 Grp 2      NA
# 3 Grp 3       9

Would I use this approach? Probably no, but just wanted to show how to piggyback on the fact that pmax treats empty sets differently.
